# angularjs injecting partial view from controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, angularjs

Inside angularjs app view page I have unordered list like

```
<ul>
   <li> Item 1 </li>
   <li> Item 2 </li>
   <li> Item 3 </li>
</ul>
```

on the same page I have placeholder where I want to load partial views with content returned from controller

```
<div id="partialResults">
</div>
```

I was thinking to onclick on each iteam call controller function and then return partial view from controller to the view.

How can I do this in angularjs or is there better way for this situations. This way I would do in asp.net-mvc sending ajax request and return partial view from controller.

Comment: Controllers in angular js are bound to views, so angular loads them both up. You're better off reading a tutorial on this stuff.

Comment: ui-router is a good framework to use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work. Call a function in your controller with the HTML view you want to include:

```
<li ng-click='loadPartial("item1.html")'> Item 1 </li>
```

Then in your controller you set it as active in a variable:

```
$scope.loadPartial = function(link) {
    $scope.currentPartial = $scope.basePath + link;
}
```

Then in the div:

```
<div id="partialResults" ng-include="currentPartial">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use History API for partial views. Refer this link...         http://html5demos.com/history
https://css-tricks.com/using-the-html5-history-api/
http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html